# How to check if NSString returned by objectForKey is "" objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm not exactly sure how to check whether a NSString is blank or not, I've got this code...

```
 NSString *imageName = [myItem objectForKey:@"iconName"];

        if(imageName == @"")
        {
        }
```

And when I do a print on the myItem object, it comes up as..

```
iconName = "";
```

At the NSString *imageName line, I noticed in xcode in the console it says

> "variable is not NSString"

Which I don't get as iconName is saved and stored on the parse.com database as a NSString.

When I run that code though it doesn't seem to realise that imageName = "";

Comment: To tell if a string is zero length you can (duh!) check the `length` of the string (== 0) or do `isEqualToString:@""`.

Comment: (But note that comparing strings (or any object) with `==` is not a good idea -- you're comparing addresses, not values.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this code block when comparing strings:

```
if ([imageName isEqualToString:@""]){
}
```

Comment: Given the code in the question, I think `[imageName isEqual:@""]` would be better. `isEqualToString:` is faster, but relies on `imageName` being a string. Given that it came from a dictionary, using the slower function is probably wiser.

Comment: @StevenFisher but he declared imageName as NSString. If he did not, you would be right indeed.

Comment: While he did declare it that way, it doesn't mean that myItem will actually return a string.

Comment: @lnafziger Yes, the thing is declaring imageName as NSString. If myItem can return any object, he should not declare imageName NSString. Am I right?

Comment: @UlasSancak The return type of `objectForKey:` is `id`. That means the compiler will allow you to assign the return value to a variable of any type, regardless what the type actually is at runtime. Steven Fisher's point was that `isEqual:` would be safer in that situation, given that there's no guarantee that the object will actually be an instance of `NSString` at runtime.

Comment: Should and did are often different.  As @StevenFisher says, it is safer not to assume.

Comment: Why would there be no guarantee? I store iconName as a string in the first place on the database, I don't see how it can then become something different, unless there's something I'm not aware of?

Comment: Not sure why I've got a down vote. I asked what I thought was a legitimate question with a definite answer. The first responder explained something I was not aware of, information I'm sure will be useful for other people who are learning obj-c. Evidently that earns you a down vote in somebodies view.

Comment: @phil good question.  I find it to be extremely poor form to down vote anything here without a comment explaining why.  Unfortunately though, not everyone agrees and you do run into that, so it is best not to let it bug you too much.  That's what we are here for!

Comment: @Inafziger, thanks, the problem is I must of been right on the edge, and that down vote means I've been banned from asking any more questions.

Comment: As to why to use `isEqual:`: It's more a general principle than a rule. Your "default" should be to use `isEqual:`; use `isEqualToString:` when you're absolutely sure it's a string (generally, if it's created earlier in the same function) **and** performance matters. Unless you're in a loop, it's never going to matter. It's far ruder of your app to crash vs. taking an extra few milliseconds. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `isEqualToString` to compare two strings. If you just use == then you are comparing two pointers.

You could also check to see if the object you are receiving is a NSString by:

```
if ([imageName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to write a sanity check for this value, NSString *websiteURL = [detailDict objectForKey:@"website_url"]. I found I couldn't compare to nil, NULL or use the length method to check validity (length, led to a crash). This worked...

Answer (score 3):

Although you have a few answers already, here is my take.

First of all, your warning (not error) can be fixed like this:

```
 NSString *imageName = (NSString *)[myItem objectForKey:@"iconName"];
```

Then, I would check to make sure that the string is not `nil` **and** that it is not blank.  The easiest way to do this in objective-C is to check the length of the string, since if it nil it will return 0, and if it is empty, it will return 0:

```
if([imageName length] == 0)
{
   // This is an empty string.
}
```

As @jlehr points out, if there is the possibility that imageName may not actually be stored as a string, then in order to prevent a crash you need to check first.  (This may or may not be needed, depending on the logic of your application):

```
if ([imageName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] 
{
    if([imageName length] == 0)
    {
        // This is an empty string.
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that the return type of `objectForKey:` is `id`, the cast to `NSString *` is meaningless. And if the type of `imageName` turns out to be something other than `NSString *` at runtime, the call to `length` could trigger an exception.

Comment: @jlehr While that is true, if you store a string there then you will get a string back.  If there is the possibility of getting something other than a string, the class type should be checked accordingly using `if ([imageName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

The `"variable is not NSString"` is probably because `objectForKey:` return an `id`.

To  should use `[imageName isEqualToString:@""]`.